# Monte carlo $\pi$, how is $\pi$ being deduced here?

Tags: pi, monte-carlo

I am following a programming tutorial that has the following slide:

Area of circle $S_c = \pi\times r^2$

Area of square $S_s = 2r \times 2r = 4r^2$

Therefore $\pi = 4S_c/S_s$

[Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OEQN.jpg)

I cannot see how the author has arrived at the calculation for $\pi$ however.  Can someone please advise?

Comment: compute $S_c/S_s$ with the formula the author gives...

Comment: The author simply computed the ratio o$S_c/S_s$

Comment: Throw $n$ darts at the square.  Let $m$ be the number of darts that fell inside the circle. The ratio $m/n$ approximates the ratio $S_c/S_s$ if the darts are uniformly distributed in the square.  Four times the $m/n$ ratio slowly converges to $\pi$ as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author says that

- $\displaystyle S_c=\pi r^2$;
- $\displaystyle S_s=4r^2$.

Therefore$$\frac{4S_c}{S_s}=\frac{4\pi r^2}{4r^2}=\pi.$$